# A non root user can not execute idea.sh successfully

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

when a non root user executes `idea.sh`, can not start the IDEA, the output just as follows:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

When root user executes `idea.sh`, can start IDEA successfully!

the `JAVA_HOME` is ok

Comment: Where is your installation located? Have you tried checking its owner/permissions and changing them using `chown`/`chmod`?

Comment: I installed it in a non root user directory. Its permissions is right.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective it looks like you have custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options for non root user, which contains **MaxPermSize**.

Solution to fix it:

1. You can copy **idea.vmoptions** file from root's IDEA_HOME to user's folder
2. You can just remove **idea.vmoptions** from IDEA_HOME